# How can I cancel the changes in the form and return to state it loads

Tags: c#, forms

I have created a button in Revit in which I press a form loads. The form includes ComboBox and some buttons to add or delete. A Cancel button is provided in the form. I intend that when the user hits the cancel button every change which has been made will be ignored and when the user clicks the button in Revit the form loads in the initial state, I mean no changes exist.

I did the following but it does not work!
When form loads, I back up the form with the aid of static class (FormState) which has a property (PreviousForm )

```
    public class FormState
{
    public static Form PreviousForm { get; set; }
    public static DialogResult diagResult { get; set; }
}

        private void QuantifyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Back up the form
        FormState.PreviousForm = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)sender;
     }
```

Then, When I hit the cancel button, I do the following:

```
        private void q_btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        FormState.diagResult = this.DialogResult;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Finally, when I press the button in the Revit in order to load the form, I do as:

```
                    if (FormState.diagResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    FormState.PreviousForm.ShowDialog();
                }
```

But when the form loads, all changes exist and it seems the cancel button does not work properly.

Comment: Quite expected, since you are showing the _same_ form again. But you can do this without any outside knowledge: Have a _model_ holding the form's _data_. On Showing the form, you load that data, but at the same time, you'll make a (deep) copy and bind the form to that. Now if the changes are accepted, you save the changed model (model copy), if it is canceled, you simply dispose the model copy.

Comment: Thanks Fildor. How can I do the procedure you mentioned in the code?

Comment: The question is not quite clear, you need to let us know if you are using data-binding, your data source (DataSet? EntityFramework? ...), the way that you pass data to the form and etc.